# Создать регулярное выражение, в котором между сокращениями городов, улиц, зданий и т.д. и названиями может быть указано несколько пробелов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо создать регулярное выражение, в котором между сокращениями (со знаком точки) городов, улиц, зданий и т.д. и названиями может быть указано несколько пробелов, в том числе знак перехода на новый абзац как в ворде), или их отсутствие
Имеется небольшой список сокращений, а именно:

ул.
зд.
наб.
г.
пос.
ш.
пом.
оф.

и любые названия, например, Ростов-на-Дону, Курчатовское шоссе, и прочее. И между этими сокращениями может быть любой символ или их количество, даже знак перехода на новый абзац

Примеры такие:
г.Ноябрьск
ул.  Пушкина
зд. 3
ул.10
пом. 14
оф.  13

Comment: p.s. И между этими сокращениями и названиями

Comment: А что должно делать это регулярное выражение? Вы пробовали его написать самостоятельно? Что не получилось?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Comment: Мне нужно исключить подобные сочетания для перевода документов и хочу составить набор исключения для того, чтобы данные выражения не учитывались при сегментации при переводе документов

Comment: грубо говоря, это от выражение от 1 до 3 символов, потом точка, потом неизвестно сколько пробелов, потом название

Comment: от 1 до 3 символов - подразумевается текстовые символы, нецифровые, непробельные

Comment: пока получается так: [а-я].\s[а-я] . Я не знаю ,как указать, что количество символов до точки  должно быть от 1 до 3 и пробелов может либо не быть, либо также от 1 до 3. В этом пока вся проблема. Помогите, пожалуйста, если нетрудно.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s{0,3}[а-яёА-ЯЁ]*[.]+\s{0,3}[а-яёА-ЯЁ]*
```

По регулярным выражениям есть статья на Habr: https://habr.com/ru/post/545150/

Там есть ссылки на инструменты где можно протестировать и поправить регулярные выражения. Например: https://regex101.com/